# sql server function to find minimum of N number of values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-function

I would like to find the minimum value inside select statement like;
 assuming have function called findMin,

```
select
   select min from findMin(firstDate,secondDate,thirdDate,....NDate),
   firstDate,
   secondDate,
   thirdDate,
   .... (having N number of dates)
from
   dateTable
```

I am having trouble to write findMin function inside sql server 2008 R2.

Any helps?

Thanks

Comment: Do a correlated sub-select where you now are trying to do findmin. But how does your table look??? Lots of columns for dates, maybe better idea to have several rows instead?

Comment: You are looking for the `greatest()` and `least()` functions, which many databases support.  But not SQL Server.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yeah thats is also what I know and thats why I have asked about it

Comment: thanks @jarlh I have written subselect with temp values approach like answer below inside outer apply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this to find the earliest date:

```
SELECT
   MinDate.mDate,
   dt.firstDate,
   dt.secondDate,
   dt.thirdDate
FROM
   dateTable dt
outer apply
(
  SELECT min(mDate)
  FROM (values(firstDate), (secondDate), 
       (ThirdDate), (FourthDate)) x(mDate)
) MinDate
```

Comment: thanks @t-clausen.dk I have removed outer apply and added it direclty inside select statement

Comment: that is also a way to do it. I am not sure which perform faster. If I were you, I would compare performance with @GordonLinoff's answer before using this method

Comment: Is the performance comparable?  `Apply` is often quite optimized and might work very well in this case.

Comment: not able to compare why is number of arguments is not that stable so in @GordonLinoff ' s solution if # of args are 20 then no way to do that

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server doesn't support `least()` and `greatest()` (alas).  If the values are never `NULL`, the following logic is cumbersome but does what you want for five dates:

```
select (case when date1 <= date2 and date1 <= date3 and date1 <= date4 and date1 <= date5
             then date1
             when date2 <= date3 and date2 <= date4 and date2 <= date5
             then date2
             when date3 <= date4 and date3 <= date5
             then date3
             when date4 <= date5
             then date4
             else date5
         end)
```

This can be easily generalized to more dates.  It just requires more logic.

There is another alternative which is to unpivot the data and then reaggregate it.  However, that is much more expensive than just doing operations within a single row.